# Ajax function can't save the data from rails form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When i hit savebutton the form is not submitted,what could be wrong with my code?Thank you in advance.I am using Rails 3.1

FORM

```
 <%=form_for :user ,:remote=>true do |f|%>
 <%= f.label :school %>
 <%= f.text_field :school,:size=>"45",:class=>"round",:id=>"school" %>
 <%= f.submit "save and continue",{:class=>"savebutton" }%>
 <%end%>
```

JQUERY(application.js)

```
$(".savebutton").bind('click',function() {  
  $('form').submit(function() { 
    var formToSubmit = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
      url: $(this).attr('action'), 
      data: formToSubmit,
      dataType: "JSON" 
     });
    return false; 
  });
});
```

CONTROLLER

```
class SchoolController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def create
    @school = current_user.schools.build(params[:school].merge(:user => current_user))

    @school = current_user.school.build(params[:school].merge(:user => current_user))

    if @school.save
      respond_with @school
    else
      respond_with @school.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well @vinceh's answer is definitely the way you should be doing this, you still *can* do it the old-fashioned way like you are.

The `.submit()` method does not submit the form (you may be thinking it does), but instead binds the form's `submit` event to the method you provide. So right now, when you click the submit button, all it does is set up the callback, but then you `return false` so the form never actually gets submitted.

You should just be able to get rid of the surrounding `$('.savebutton).click(...)` handler and put the `$('form').submit(...)` handler directly in your javascript, so that when the page loads, the callback is registered immediately. You don't need to worry about handling the `.savebutton` click specifically.

Also, your Ajax request probably needs a `type: 'POST'` or `type: 'PUT'`, since `$.ajax` defaults to GET requests.

Comment: So you mean like the changes i just made?Look at the form and ajax function

Comment: Well if you use `:remote => true`, you should just be able to get rid of your javascript code altogether. But if you want to do it the old way, you couldn't use `:remote => true`, and you would get rid of the `$(.savebutton)` code (you changed it to a `bind` instead of just getting rid of it).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use ajax, you need to add `:remote => true` in your `form_for` and with Rails you don't need to explicitly call `$.ajax` if your form has `:remote => true`.  Read [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/using-unobtrusive-javascript-and-ajax-with-rails-3/) for a good tutorial on how to use AJAX in your Rails applications.